# Why is IIS stripping web page extensions all of a sudden?

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

This morning I pushed a new .Net web site (fw 4.6.1, previously 4.5.1) out to production.  IIS (I assume) stripped the extensions from all web pages (ie. index.aspx just became index).  I've had these web sites running for 8+ years using IIS rewrites.  It looks like then IIS saw the "extensionless" web pages, the rewrite kicked in and sent it to a non-existent location, producing a 404.

I also did a Windows update 3 days ago (could have missed this issue since but unlikely). The rewrite rule basically says, if you can't find the page, look for the page in the "Clients" subdirectory. The rule looks like:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Client Relocation" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" negate="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="Clients/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I was able to work around the issue by removing the rewrite rule in a subdirectory:

```
  <rewrite>
      <rules>
          <remove name="Client Relocation" />
      </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

So, it would appear the extension was stripped, then IIS gets the page and thinks it doesn't exist so the rewrite rule takes effect.

So, my question is: who/what is stripping the extension and how can I stop it from doing so?

Comment: Rewrite rules do not change URLs in your web browser. So if you observed such changes, the possibility is likely to be from your web application. FRT can tell the truth, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: I installed FRT, never used it before, and trying to reproduce the error.  It's showing a missing .gif (which is correct) but not on the web page.  On my development server, it's showing the .aspx without the extension properly.  I'll see if I can do something on production and report back.

Comment: I'm still working on the FRT thing but in reference to your comment about the web application, I put the web page in the debugger and the last executed line is:

    window.location.href = "/lmw/main/index.aspx";

Then in the .Net program I put a break point on the first line of index.aspx and in the immediate window typed:
Context.Request.ServerVariables["PATH_INFO"];
"/lmw/main/index"
As you can see there is no extension there.  So, what would take off the extension between the JS .href = statement and the called .Net page?

Comment: FRT no traces.  It's configured for all pages, errors 100-999, and all providers.  windows.location.href = /lmw/main/index.aspx but it shows up as /lmw/main/index

Answer (score 0):

Lex Li put me on the right track with the comment about the application and failed request tracing.  Turned out to be the App_Start/RouteConfig.cs file got modified and added:

```
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
```

Not exactly sure how or why but commenting out the AutoRedirectMode put the extensions back on.  If I could give the answer to Lex's comment, I would have.